# Detecting js using class and document.documentElement

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to figure out how this code is detecting if js is enabled in the web browser or not. There is no any check or if or anything else. Message is displayed when there is class no-js that is simple. But where the actual checking is made?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" class="no-javascript">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            .warning {
                display: none;
            }

            .no-javascript .warning {
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="warning">Enable js</div>
        <script>
            var elDocument = document.documentElement;
            elDocument.className = elDocument.className.replace(/(^|\s)no-javascript(\s|$)/, '$1');
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: It's not "checking" anything. It can only run if JS is enabled.

Comment: Be aware that there also is the `<noscript>` tag that renders only if JavaScript is not enabled, cf. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript

Answer (score 4):

What this code does is display the warning initially, then immediately tries to hide it with Javascript. If Javascript is disabled, the code does not run and it cannot remove the warning, therefore the user sees it.

Be aware that there also is the  tag that renders only if JavaScript is not enabled, cf. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript